# Selecting multiple tables for one value

Tags: c#, mysql

What im trying to do is select multiple tables and search for one value which should be under the column "wa"

Code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            MySqlDataAdapter SDA = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM 'arrests', 'bolo', 'tickets', 'warrant' WHERE wa=@a", con);
            SDA.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", textBox1.Text);
            SDA.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        } catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Stacktrace: \n" + ex.StackTrace);
            MessageBox.Show("MySQL Error", "Error MySQl");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any error or exception you got ? 
Make sure you have 'wa' column name in all table from which you want to get data !

Comment: The exception was because of the multiple tables and I have the wa column

Comment: @JordieDevs , In this case you can use UNION clause something like this 
(select * from arrests where wa=@a)
UNION
(select* from bolo where wa=@a) and further more .

In actual your call over database is ambiguous for column name !